# Optimize SOQL query

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, soql, dynamic-soql

I have a condition where I need to get list of Contacts based on many conditions, which I'm able to do but now I need to limit the number of Contacts per Account.

For the new scenario I need to switch back to inner queries, so for this case I need to switch to inner queries.
Now when I use the inner queries for Contacts my batch size is too large, I want to limit the number of Contacts per Account without using inner queries.

SOQL Without Inner Query:

```
'Select Id,Name FROM Contacts WHERE '+ where_cond+ '
```

SOQL with Inner Query:

```
'SELECT Id,(Select Id,Name FROM Contacts WHERE '+ where_cond+ ' LIMIT : numberOfContacts) FROM Account'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify your direct Contact query

```
Select Id, Name FROM Contacts WHERE '+ where_cond+ '
```

to select a specific number of Contacts per Account. Instead, limit your outer query with filters on the Account:

```
SELECT Id,
       (Select Id,Name FROM Contacts WHERE '+ where_cond+ ' LIMIT : numberOfContacts) 
FROM Account
WHERE <some condition>
```

to reduce the total amount of data and total number of rows being processed to an acceptable level, or utilize an Account-centered batch class running at a lower batch size.

Alternately, postprocess your Contact query results in Apex to isolate a limited group of Contacts per Account. Adding `ORDER BY AccountId, [some other field]` is likely to be helpful there.